# Jquery: Dropkick plugin - Form submit onchange

Tags: jquery, forms, submit, onchange, jquery-dropkick

Hi i get a form without button submit, who work very well without Dropkick and send by POST method a variable called "fonction":

```
<form name="recherche_cat" method="post" class="ass_select">
<select name="fonction" onchange='submit()' tabindex="3" size="1">
    <option value="default">default</option>
    <option value="1">mot1</option>
    <option value="2">mot2</option>
</select>
</form>
```

But when i used dropkick, it does'nt work anymore.
I try this:

```
$('.ass_select').dropkick({
  change: function (value, label) {
  $(this).closest('form').submit();
  }
});
```

Page reload but without post the value.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/kx2VT/1/ what jQuery version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Your `onchange='submit()'` no longer fires because jQuery does not warrant firing handlers attached without jQuery.

Instead, assuming you have that `submit` function declared, use:

```
$('.ass_select').dropkick({
  change: submit
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kx2VT/2/)

Note that inside the handler, `this` points to the `form` instead of the `select` element now.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but i dont know what to declare inside the submit function, to get the same effect than my onchange='submit()'. How tell in jquery that i want reload the page with my var value ?

Comment: Can you edit the question to add the `submit` function's code? I'm not sure what you mean with "reload the page with the var value".

Comment: Well the problem is i dont get any function submit :) I would like something who do the same thing than a form when you use the submit button with POST method.

Comment: @casp In that case, the code you posted should work fine. Here's another variation that also does a POST request submitting the form: http://jsfiddle.net/kx2VT/5/

Comment: Hum ok .. well it does'nt work; but if you say that it should. I supposed there is a conflict between my cms (spip) and the javascript in the order of the action... But what is strange it's that it's working if i use a button submit. Thanks you. i will continue searching.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem.
I should not add the dropkick class (on my example class="ass_select") on the form, but on the select.
Like this the submit is alright.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$('.ass_select').dropkick({
  change: function (value, label) {
      $(this.form).submit();//changed here
  }
});
```